# Can't access web server behind pfSense using second public IP

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, pfsense

I have a /29 block of static IPs, one of which I have assigned to a web server on the LAN using VIP, NAT, Rules. Firewall logs show data is being passed successfully to the server, I don't see any related issues in apache logs, but I receive a "Server Unavailable" message on the browser (accessing from outside LAN of course).

- verified firewalld/iptables are disabled
- verified SSL configuration
- verified the server (apache) is listening on LAN IP
- vhost is set with fqdn, allow rule, etc.
- confirmed access from LAN
- no errors in apache logs

I'm at that point where it seems like I must have missed something simple and right in front of my face, something that only fresh eyes will see, lol!

Let me know if you need any other details. Thanks!

Note: **web_services** are set to HTTP and HTTPS, **www_service** is the web server itself.

NAT:
[image: NAT settings]

Firewall rule:
[image: Firewall Rule]

Virtual IP:
[image: VIrtual IP]

**UPDATE:**

curl -v http://foo.bar.net show 301 redirect to HTTPS
curl -v https://foo.bar.net gives TIMEOUT

So why would firewall show web traffic allowed but curl gives TIMEOUT?

Comment: Can you verify that your webserver is listening in 443/tcp. It looks like nothing is listening for https traffic on your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as per usual, I cleared out all the firewall configurations related to the web server, **updated to newer snapshot**, rebooted pfSense, configured them all from scratch, and booyah! Landed on the login page.

I suppose you could tack it up to some lingering states. Anyway, all is well.

In the end, configuration requires public IP configured as Virtual IPs, standard practice NAT and firewall rules, and proper vhost configuration. I didn't tweak anything on the web server itself, so I think it was just some leftover junk in pfSense.

Thanks for the help! The curl command really helped in troubleshooting.

Comment: Probably way too much effort and unnecessary reconfiguration "from scratch" for not following best practices of simply [resetting states](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Reset_States)

Comment: I actually reset states several times. But I did forget to mention I ran an update before reboot so it may have had something to do with being on a slightly outdated snapshot. (answer updated)